# 60 GHz radiation

Tags: radiation, electron

I have always gotten great answers on this site so I thought I'd give this one a shot. In looking into 5G technology, I found that it radiates at 60 GHz, which apparently is in the oxygen absorption spectra, and that because this radiation affects the electron spin of the O2 atoms, it could hinder oxygen getting into the respiratory system. Would anyone have any insight or response to this? thanks.

Comment: Where did you find this information? Can you add a link or a screenshot?

Comment: All the websites that link the two have a LOT of other questionable content.

Comment: https://t.co/XCKsOepu9a?amp=1. It's not only about the spectra, but the amount of towers and radiation, which is 10x from many common sources.

Comment: [A search result I am going through now. Long article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6765906/)

Comment: "The frequency range 60–65 GHz was extra analyzed as in this group a larger number of publications was identified (in comparison to the other groups)." Because it's in the oxygen absorption spectra!

Comment: Exposure of the eyes leads to the absorption of the EM energy by the cornea characterized by a freewater content of 75% and a thickness of 0.5 mm. Ocular lesions have been found after high-intensity exposure of aneye (3 W/cm2, 6 min) (yet this is 30x higher than 0.1W/cm2 for workers suggested). The caterogenic cumulative effects on eyes is a concern also.  https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S1759078711000122 Application of millimeter waves for the pain therapy showedsome positive results

Comment: You are suggesting a safety issue without evidence. Where is the backup in reducing O2 lung absorption. There is  a signal attenuation of 16 dB/km peak of oxygen-induced  absorption  around  60 GHz

Comment: https://scientists4wiredtech.com/wireless-at-60-ghz-has-unique-oxygen-absorption-properties/

Comment: The s4wt link doesn't mention anything about lungs and absorption. (The link I posted above from ncbi considers only studies related to thermal effects and not oxygen absorption effects)

Comment: OP's *ourgreaterdestiny* link "*The impact of oxygen molecules spinning the electrons is that it makes the hemoglobin unable to uptake the oxygen and get it to the rest of your body.*" There is no source cited for this claim other than a possible YouTube video link. OP please link to reputable primary sources.

Comment: thanks everyone for the help. I am looking for just that "the impact of oxygen molecules spinning electrons...limiting our oxygen. I have true bad feelings about it, and 5G is all over the world and in 10x the amount of towers. Will continue to look

Comment: Are you sure 5g uses 60 GHz? The wikipedia article doesn't mention 60 GHz.

Comment: it uses a range from like 5-100 depending on what application. Poster above posted a great link. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6765906/ where a noticed increase in radiation effects occurred near 60 GHz , in my opinion because of the oxygen absorption spectra. However until I can prove that this radiation interacts with oxygen molecules to lead to a decrease in our ability to get it into our lungs, this may be stagnent

Comment: In those cited tests they were really lighting up the test subjects with a lot of radiation. It sounds like most of the effects observed were thermal effects. And quite a few studies found no effects. I suspect you are fixating on a red herring.

Comment: The great advantage of using an atmospheric absorption band for comms is that it gives a well-defined size to the coverage area, allowing reliable and dense cell spacing, for high area throughput. It you hit any part of the body hard enough with EM, or hit any part of the body hard enough with a hammer, you're going to cause damage.

Comment: @mkeith whats "fixating on a red herring" for non native speakers?

Comment: @mkeith the german wikipedia mentions 40Ghz are approved for 5G in 2019 with 60 and 80Ghz are in discussion for future use. Also 60GHz Links seem to be already in use as short distance links between company buildings and glasfiber endpoints.

Comment: "Fixate" is a standard word that can be looked up in a dictionary. A red herring is similar to a dead-end road. It seems like a good idea, but after you investigate for a long time, it proves to be of no use. A false hypothesis, or distraction from a true solution of a problem.

Comment: I also wanted to add this source on microwave absorption of oxygen. Possibly it applies to the 5G networks. https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/4963/RLE-TR-087-14236979.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Summary:

- Frequencies around 60 GHz are a very small portion of the total bands planned for 5G communications.
- The factors which make 60 GHz of possible concern for health also make it undesirable for communication over any distance.
- Advantage may be taken of the high absorption at 60 GHz to allow frequency reuse - but this will necessarily also utilise very low power levels to retain the advantage of rapid atmospheric absorption of the signal.

**_______________________________**

5G uses frequencies in 3 bands
The high band is unlikely to be used for some while as the lower bands are easier to utilise.  Given the extremely wide range of available frequencies available, any band which exhibited oxygen absorption, or any other effect which decreased propagation ability, would be avoided by operators. There is the potential for taking advantage of the short range aspects to allow frequency reuse - discussed [here](https://www.rfglobalnet.com/doc/fixed-wireless-communications-at-60ghz-unique-0001)

[image]

From Wikipedia [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_high_frequency)

Many countries do not propose frequency allocations in the 60 GHZ region.
Non 60 GHz   . Fom [here](https://www.arrow.com/en/research-and-events/articles/what-frequency-spectrum-will-5g-technology-use-and-how-does-this-compare-to-4g#:%7E:text=The%205G%20frequency%20band%20plans,GHz%20to%2086%20GHz%20range.)

> The 5G frequency band plans are much more complex, as the frequency spectrum for sub-6 GHz 5G spans 450 MHz to 6 GHz, and millimeter-wave 5G frequencies span 24.250 GHz to 52.600 GHz, and also include unlicensed spectrum. Additionally, there may be 5G spectrum in the 5925 to 7150 MHz range and 64 GHz to 86 GHz range. Therefore, 5G will include all previous cellular spectrum and a large amount spectrum in the sub-6 GHz range, and beyond sub- 6 GHz is many times current cellular spectrum (Table 2 and Table 3). The initial 3GPP release of 5G New Radio Non-standalone (5G NR) standards included several sub-6 GHz frequency bands, designated FR1 (Table 2). The second 3GPP 5G release after IMT-2020 will include FR2 frequency bands in the millimeter-wave spectrum (Table 3).

> As with previous cellular generations and 3GPP releases, various regions and countries will also likely adopt unique spectrum for 5G uses. The US FCC, for example, is considering opening 5.925 GHz to 6.425 GHz and 6.425 GHz to 7.125 GHz  for unlicensed used and is consulting adding mobile broadband capability in the 3.7 GHz to 4.2 GHz spectrum. Currently, the FCC is actioning spectrum in the 27.5 GHz to 28.35 GHz, 24.25 GHz to 24.45 GHz, and 24.75 GHz 25.25 GHz, range for millimeter-wave 5G use. The FCC may also be considering opening 3.7 GHz to 4.2 GHz mid-band frequencies for 5G, and may also be considering opening 4.9 GHz public safety bands for 5G access. Moreover, the FCC may also make additional bands available for 5G in the 2.75 GHz, 26 GHz, and 42 GHz bands. In December 2018 the FCC announced an incentive action in the 37.6 GHz to 38.6 GHz, 38.6 GHz to 40 GHz, and 47.2 GHz to 48.2 GHz. Most other developing countries are undergoing similar considerations of spectrum allocation for 5G use cases.

---

> ... Could operating at frequencies near the oxygen absorption spectra but not on it still have an affect on our breathing? Or could simply the amount of radiation (10x) due to higher frequencies attenuating less affect us in any way. ...

I did a university undergrad project in 1973 (!)  [an RFID shop door alarm when such things almost didn't exist] where the the health effects of RF were considered and I did a fair amount of reading then of the avaiiable literature and have kept an informal watch on the subject over the subsequent 47 years [! :-) ]. There have been a vast number of claims in all conceivable areas of health impacts from EM radiation of every sort, and vast numbers of studies to see if there is any truth in any of the claims. I conclude that while there MAY be some EM health effects, if they exist they are "down in the noise" and not a significant health factor for most people in most situations in life - and maybe for essentially nobody. There ARE studies which claim otherwise - but if these were clearly demonstrated and able to be readily replicated they would have been the subject of major exposes in the major scientific literature. As an oldish EE I'm happy enough that it is safe enough overall. If you look both ways one more time when crossing roads you will increase your longevity more effectively than being overly concerned about EM radiation .

Comment: Thanks a lot, Russell for all this information. There is a lot to analyze, and I brought up this topic because of the large increase in number of towers globally, as well as the frequency, which I know a lot more about now. I just find it hard to imagine that there wouldn't be a lot of affects, maybe only some of which have to do with oxygen absorption. Could operating at frequencies near the oxygen absorption spectra but not on it still have an affect on our breathing? Or could simply the amount of radiation (10x) due to higher frequencies attenuating less affect us in any way.

Comment: Considering there are thousands of satellites in orbit along with 100's of thousands of new 5G towers, I can't imagine their aren't many adverse effects. Thank you for your very informative and accurate response, will continue to look into this.

Comment: @Af91 I did a university undergrad project in 1973 (!)  [an RFID shop door alarm when such things almost didn't exist] where the the effects of RF were considered and I did a fair amount of reading then of the avaiiable literature and have kept an informal watch on the subject over the subsequent 47 years [! :-) ]. There have been a vast number of claims in all conceivable areas of health impacts from EM radiation of every sort, and vast numbers of studies to see if there is any truth in any of the claims. ...

Comment: I conclude that while there MAY be some EM health effects, if they exist they are "down in the noise" and not a significant health factor for most people in most situations in life - and maybe for essentially nobody. There ARE studies which claim otherwise - but if these were clearly demonstrated and able to be readily replicated they would have been the subject of major exposes in the major scientific literature. ...

Comment: ... As an oldish EE I'm happy enough that it is safe enough overall. If you look both ways one more time when crossing roads you will increase your longevity more effectively than being overly concerned about EM radiation .

Comment: I'd usually agree with you. I was mostly concerned with the oxygen absorption spectra, but don't know enough about 5G to know. thanks